# MySQL - multiple concurrent updates

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, concurrency

I have created a location based App for Android-IOS and I use NodeJS for my backend. The location of my users is being updated every X seconds with an HTTP Request to the NodeJS Server. Let’s suppose that I will have 10.000 concurrent requests/sec that update different users location data, could MySQL handle this volume? Or it will crash?

Comment: What's the time frame?

Comment: @TheImpaler what do you mean by Time frame? 10.000 concurrent res/sec.

Comment: "per second" -- Please add that to the question.

Comment: @Ashkan No, I use MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you'll use MySQL-specific SQL something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO location (user_id,long, lat) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE long=?, lat=?;
```

on a table with a definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE location (
 user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 long  FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 lat   FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

That's likely the simplest table you can use for the purpose. If you need to search the table based on location you'll probably also need this index for bounding-box searches.

```
 INDEX location_lat_long_user_id (lat, long, user_id)
```

So, at a minimum for each update MySql needs to access the `user_id` key, and may also need to update the other index.

If you put much more information in, or more indexes on, that table your inserts and updates will get even more complex for MySql to handle.

10K of those transactions per second is a *very high number* for a single MySQL server. If you configure your node connection pools correctly, your MySQL server won't crash. But your node servers may slow down uncomfortably, or even run low on RAM.

If your app scales up to the 10K/sec point you may want to consider setting up a [MySQL cluster](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/faq.html). But, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), don't do that until your app has scaled up. It takes a while to get thousands of users.  In the meantime your time and money is far better spent on your features than on your infrastructure. (Ask me how I know this when you have an hour or two to spare.)

But, there are a couple of more ways to handle this kind of workload gracefully.

1. Use the inherent queueing mechanisms built in to nodejs. For these position updates, use a fairly small MySQL connection pool. When all the connections in the pool are active, node will queue up your incoming position-report API requests more-or-less automatically. This will allow your server to slow down gracefully when it gets short bursts of position updates.
2. Don't record position data nearly so often.  Ordinary GPS data is only accurate to a couple of meters at best. If your subjects are walking it will take at least a couple of seconds for them to move one meter.
3. Only update the database when you know your subjects' handsets have moved more than a certain distance. The best way to do this is in your app. Make it only report a new location when the subject has moved a certain distance. That way you'll avoid repetitive updates from stationary subjects. That will save a *lot* of power on the handsets.
4. With your updates also sent a timestamp and motion vector in degrees/second. And, only send it when either the position or motion vector changes significantly.  Your updates might look like this:

   ```
    time        long       lat           dlong      dlat
   1581106542  -73.98508   40.74780    -0.0004     -0.0005
   ```

Then if you need to guess a current position for your subject, you can multiply the vector by the time difference and add it to the position. This will help a lot if your subjects are moving fast (planes, trains, and automobiles) and you need to guess their positions accurately on your backend.

Comment: thank you for your response. Is it a good idea to handle these requests first in an MQ (I thought about RabbitMQ) and then sending one by one (by MQ) to MySQL? What do you think?

Comment: Yes, absolutely use a message queue for these position updates if you have access to one. It's a good solution because you can monitor your backlog during busy times of day.You might also consider using an in-memory key/value store like redis in place of MySql. None of this changes my view that one position update per second is far too many updates for a scalable system  design.

Comment: I use Redis to fetch for example a product details page faster. How can be Redis useful in the case of updating location users data continuously ? Could you explain me your logic using Redis instead of MySQL?

Comment: It's hard to say which geo data storage alternative is best because you haven't explained what you want to do with your geo data. Redis has some geo search functions.